# Java nio Path subpath returns incomplete Path

Tags: java, file, path, nio

My question concerns Java NIO Paths. I am using the `Path` class's `subpath()` method in order to split a full path into subpaths. However, when the subpaths are returned, the `Path` object that is returned has `null` in the `stringValue` variable of the `Path`. This makes it useless for checking with `endsWith()` and other Path functions.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
Path subpath = oldPath.subpath (1, oldPath.getNameCount ());
    if (otherPath.endsWith (subpath))
    {
      //do something
    }
```

However, the `otherPath.endsWith(subpath)` is turning up false, even when it should not. I can insert a line such as the following before the `if()`:

```
subpath.toFile().exists();
```

and after execution of that line, the `stringValue` field is filled in, and the `if(otherPath.endsWith(subpath)` will evaluate correctly. My question is is there any way to make sure that the subpath that is returned from the `Path.subpath()` method is fully completed, or is the way I'm creating subpaths wrong from the start?

For clarification, I am coding and running these tests on a Linux system, I don't know whether or not this will work properly on Windows or another OS.

Comment: Please give an example of `oldPath`.

Comment: `oldPath` is a relative path in the file system, such as `/usr/game/res.txt`.

Comment: That's an absolute path. But honestly, I can't reproduce your problem. You'll have to give more details of the values of `oldPath` and `subpath` and maybe about your environment.

Comment: Sorry, I realize that path was probably a poor example. For the path, I have a path `DropBox/changedFile.txt`. I'm running openSUSE, and my java version is 1.7.0_45. Basically, I want to create a path that would just be `/changedFile.txt`. What I get back is a `Path` that has no data for the `stringValue` field until an operation is called on that path, which means that I can't call `endsWith()` on the subpath until calling something else. If you can't reproduce it I suppose it could just be a system specific problem.

Comment: What `stringValue` are you referring to? Please edit your question to add these details.